# Center OwlCarousel when less than X items

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, owl-carousel

We're using OwlCarousel 1.3.3 on our responsive site. We've set the max number of items to 4.

```
$container.owlCarousel({
    items: 4,
    itemsDesktop: [1000, 4], 
    itemsDesktopSmall: [900, 3], 
    itemsTablet: [600, 2], 
    itemsMobile: [480, 1]
});
```

As long as the carousel contains 4 or more images everything works fine. But when an editor only adds 3 or less items we want those items to be centered on the page. Right now they're "left aligned" and it doesn't look very good.

The option `itemsScaleUp` is not what I'm looking for. If items is set to 4 but the carousel only contains 1 item that item would get too big.

I've found these issues on github:
https://github.com/smashingboxes/OwlCarousel2/issues/35
https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/issues/417
But nothing I find helpful.

You can see the issue in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/pstenstrm/pen/yNPJMR).

**Update:**
Looking through the source of OwlCarousel you'll see that the `.owl-wrapper` elements width gets multiplied with 2. But I can't figure out why, and if it's safe to remove the multiplier.

I've opened this [github issue](https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/issues/544) to try to get some clarification.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal online example so that we can see the issue in action?

Comment: I've added a codepen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OwlCarousel has a 2x multiplier on the `.owl-wrapper` elements width. This multiplier makes it incredibly hard to center the carousel when it's less than full.

However, this multiplier doesn't seem to have any reason to be there. Nothing seems to break when I remove it. So that's what I did, the updated owl.carousel.js can be found here: https://github.com/Vinnovera/OwlCarousel/tree/remove-width-multiplier

And I added this CSS (which is not included in the repo):

```
.owl-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 20):

In the new version of Owl Carousel 2, you need add this css:

```
.owl-stage{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

this work's for me in the version 2.

Regards!

Comment: For this to work with OwlCarousel 2, the option "center" must be set to "false".

Answer (score 6):

Instead of changing source you can use afterInit and ufterUpdate methods. Something like this:

```
        var owl = $('#carousel');
         owl.owlCarousel({
                        items 6,
                        afterInit: function () {
                            owl.find('.owl-wrapper').each(function () {
                                var w = $(this).width() / 2;
                                $(this).width(w);
                                $(this).css('margin', '0 auto');
                            });
                        },
                        afterUpdate: function () {
                            owl.find('.owl-wrapper').each(function () {
                                var w = $(this).width() / 2;
                                $(this).width(w);
                                $(this).css('margin', '0 auto');
                            });
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Savior :) ... this is awesome piece

Comment: Works with version 1.3.3

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; }
```

And this

```
.owl-carousel {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Owlcarousel2

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel();
$(window).on('resize load', function() {
    var outerStage = owl.find('.owl-stage-outer');
    var outerWidth = Number(outerStage.css('width').replace('px', ''));
    var width = Number(owl.find('.owl-stage').css('width').replace('px', ''));
    if (width < outerWidth)
        outerStage.css('left', Math.ceil(outerWidth - width)/2 + 'px');
    else 
        outerStage.css('left',0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also a possible solution which has worked for me using flexbox.

```
.owl-stage {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me with Owl Carousel 2.3.4

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```